# LOCOMOTION+UnityChanのfbxアニメーションを組み合わせたい

Tags: unity3d, genymotion

ユニティちゃんにMecanim Locomotion Starter Kitで仕入れた、
locomotion,locomotionplayerを付随させ
プラス自分で書いたスクリプトを二種類併合させてもともとユニティちゃんに備わっているアニメーションと全て使おうと考えたのですが、ユニティちゃんが固まってしまいました。
もう少し詳細に書くと

１、アニメーターの中にユニティちゃんのアニメーション（wait,damaged,lose,jump,reflesh,run,slide,umatobi）を入れました。
２、locomotionのturn on spot にmake transitionさせました。
３、スクリプトを書きました（問題なく作動はします）。
４、プレイしてみましたが、ユニティちゃんが固まりました。
　
スクリプトの量を減らすと命令通り動きます。
じゃあ、データが重いのか？と思って、新しくプロジェクトを作り極力省いた状態で、同じ方法で試したところ、ダメでした。
なぜでしょうか？
また、アニメーションを全てアニメーターの中に入れることはできないのでしょうか？

スクリプト

```java
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player: MonoBehaviour{
    public Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start(){
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("1")) {
            anim.Play ("WAIT01", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("2")) {
            anim.Play ("WAIT02", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("3")) {
            anim.Play ("WAIT03", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("4")) {
            anim.Play ("WAIT4", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("5")) {
            anim.Play ("DAMAGED00", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("6")) {
            anim.Play ("JUMP01", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("7")) {
            anim.Play ("JUMP01B", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("8")) {
            anim.Play ("LOSE00", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("9")) {
            anim.Play ("JUMP00B", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("0")) {
            anim.Play ("JUMP00", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("-")) {
            anim.Play ("REFLESH00", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("^")) {
            anim.Play ("HANDUP00", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("¥)) {
            anim.Play ("DAMAGED01", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("[")) {
            anim.Play ("RUN00_F", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("@")) {
            anim.Play ("RUN_L", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("p")) {
            anim.Play ("SLIDE", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("o")) {
            anim.Play ("RUN00_R", -1, 0f);
        }  else if (Input.GetKeyDown ("i")) {
            anim.Play ("UMATOBI00", -1, 0f);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: コードは画像ではなくテキストで張り付けをお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

スクリプトは全く問題はありませんでした。
ユニティちゃん自体に￥＾などで組んだスクリプトの指示は受け付けない仕様だったらしく、
（ユニティちゃん自体なのか、unity自体にダメなのかは研究中）
それを外して別の文字を打てばそれでokでした。